# zero vector of $M_{(2\times3)}\Bbb{R}$ and the additive inverse of it's general element.

Tags: vector-spaces

i have no idea how it will look like this
$
  M=
  \left[ {\begin{array}{ccc}
   0,0,0\\\       0,0,0\      \end{array} } \right]
$

Comment: It is simply the zero of your ring. Furthermore if $(a_{ij})$ then the additive inverse is $(-a_{ij})$.

Comment: i dont understand can you expalin further